# External expansion drive is recognized by lsusb and dmesg, but not fdisk or lsblk

Tags: usb, opensuse, usb-drive, laptop

I have a Seagate SSD expansion drive that I haven't used in a few months that I'm trying to plug into my laptop (Lenovo Yoga 460 running OpenSUSE Tumbleweed). When I plug in the expansion drive, I'm not able to access it, and I think it's making a faint beeping sound but I can't quite tell.

It's being recognized by `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bc2:231a Seagate RSS LLC Expansion Portable
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 138a:0017 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS 5011 fingerprint sensor
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04ca:705a Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 056a:504a Wacom Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

And when I run `dmesg | tail - n 20` after plugging it in, I get messages about it being recognized:

```
[  152.265336] usb 2-4: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  152.286227] usb 2-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=231a, bcdDevice= 7.07
[  152.286229] usb 2-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  152.286230] usb 2-4: Product: Expansion
[  152.286231] usb 2-4: Manufacturer: Seagate
[  152.286231] usb 2-4: SerialNumber: (Serial Number)
[  152.869311] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[  152.879025] scsi host2: uas
[  152.879653] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  Expansion        0707 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  152.880537] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[  160.903627] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
```

But when I run `sudo fdisk -l`, there's nothing listed for it, just my main laptop hard drive and the SD card I have inserted:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 238.5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk model: SanDisk SD8TB8U2
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 497E6685-2462-443E-8542-1FE0E694330E

Device         Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048    534527    532480  260M EFI System
/dev/sda2     534528    567295     32768   16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda3     567296  62007295  61440000 29.3G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4  498069504 500117503   2048000 1000M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda5   62007296 166864895 104857600   50G Linux LVM
/dev/sda6  166864896 489678847 322813952  154G Linux LVM
/dev/sda7  489678848 498069503   8390656    4G Linux swap

Partition table entries are not in disk order.


Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 14.9 GiB, 15931539456 bytes, 31116288 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: CBFAF77A-19BB-4312-BD54-1C0BDC7C6084

Device         Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1  2048 31116254 31114207 14.9G Microsoft basic data
```

Similarly, when I try to run `lsblk`, there's nothing listed there out of the ordinary:

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0 238.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1        8:1    0   260M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2        8:2    0    16M  0 part 
├─sda3        8:3    0  29.3G  0 part 
├─sda4        8:4    0  1000M  0 part 
├─sda5        8:5    0    50G  0 part /
├─sda6        8:6    0   154G  0 part /home
└─sda7        8:7    0     4G  0 part [SWAP]
mmcblk0     179:0    0  14.9G  0 disk 
└─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0  14.9G  0 part
```

Is there a way that I can still mount the hard drive?

EDIT:
Also doesn't show up with `lshw -class drive`:

```
  *-disk UNCLAIMED          
       description: SCSI Disk
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
  *-disk
       description: ATA Disk
       product: SanDisk SD8TB8U2
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sda
       version: 3101
       serial: 180131802685
       size: 238GiB (256GB)
       capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
       configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=497e6685-2462-443e-8542-1fe0e694330e logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
```

Comment: what about `lshw -class disk`?

Comment: @TimKennedy Looks like no, can't post here but I'll update the post.

Comment: it's the UNCLAIMED device in the `lshw` output.  `scsi@2:0.0.0`.   Same scsi ID as the disk above in in the `dmesg` output.   Do you have external power for the USB drive?  Or are you just plugging it in via a single USB port?   You may not have enough power for it to come fully online.